# How to create socket (Binary) server with WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, binary, sockets

How to create socket-based ( Binary Socket) WCF server server with WCF, C#?
What do I need? I need -

- Open Source Libs
- Tutorials
- Blog posts/Articles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you do such a thing? WCF is targeting a much higher abstraction level: You write a service and a client, the communication between those two is secondary but always message based. Your question is somehow analogue to "How can I use C# to write assembler code?" ;-)

However, since WCF offers multiple extension points you could probably hook into the layers where the bytes are taken from the wire and do something there. In the [description of the stack over at Nicholas Allen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2007/03/07/message-flow-interception-points.aspx) you are probably interested in bullet 5 or 6.

By the way, this blog is quite useful for the WCF developer. Nicholas Allen is one of the designers of the WCF at Microsoft. For further reading I recommend "Programming WCF Services" by Juval Löwy.